# Hold country value when submit

Tags: php

```
<label>Country <font color="8AC007">*</font> </label></td>
                     <td><select name="country" onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country"<?php                      
                            $sel_country = $myform->value('country');                     
                            if (isset($sel_country)) echo 'selected="selected"';  ?> />
                         <option value="<?php $myform->value("country");  ?>"/>Select country</option>
                         </select><br><?php  $sel_country.'sample'  ?>
                         <span class="error"><?php echo $myform->error("country"); ?></span>
```

I want to get hold with the country selected value when I submit form, instead filling the form from starting again. Here is the code Iam trying to get countries from a js file.

Apperciate your help

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, so you have to put a little effort on keeping data around when moving from page to page. Seeing this as being a form with inputs (`select` in this case), you can use `$_POST` to get hold of your submitted value in the next page.

In this case you'd use `$_POST['country']`. If you want to keep the current form filled next time the page refreshes, make the form submit to the current page, then you'll have access to that value in `$_POST`.

Other ways to keep data around:

- Sessions
- Cookies
- Database storage

But this require a little bit of additional coding in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I am right you should do it as follows. 
If you are posting your page to the server. You have the selected value. You store this and return this page. In that case I added bollow code and added `$isSelected` to the code. Normally it emtpy, but if the value is equal to the selected then you set `selected='selected'`.

```
<select name="country">
<?php
  $countryList = array("USA", "UK", "France", "Germany", "India", "Netherlands");
  $isSelected = "";
  foreach($countryList as $country)
  {
    if($_POST["country"] == $country)
    {
       $isSelected = "selected='selected'";
    }
    echo "<option value='" + $country + "' " + $isSelected + ">" + $country + "</option>";
?>
</select>
```

If you are using jquery / Ajax, you have the selected value which stays selected because the page wont refresh :-) However, you can get the value by using javascript and get value from selectbox.

------ Edit

Mmm ok, I was in the illusion you had your array in php. However you get your collection from javascript. In that case you will get this as solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var selectedCountry = "<?php echo $myform->value("country"); ?>";
</script>
<select name="country" onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country">
/* This is generated by javascript */
</select>
```

Your javascript function will be like this:

```
    function print_country(country_id){
    // given the id of the <select> tag as function argument, it inserts <option> tags
    var option_str = document.getElementById(country_id);
    option_str.length=0;
    option_str.options[0] = new Option('Select Country','');
    option_str.selectedIndex = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<country_arr.length; i++) {
        option_str.options[option_str.length] = new Option(country_arr[i],country_arr[i]);
         if(selectedCountry == country_arr[i])
         {
             option_str.options[option_str.length].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
         }
    }
}
```

----- Edit 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/eLProva/5mU76/ with filling and selecting the country

Comment: Than you for your help, could you please tell me what is "$countryList" in the above code

Comment: @ronquiq Your select options are countries isnt? So you fill the options by php from a arraylist. I will extend this. When a answer (of anyone) is correct, dont forget to mark that, this will cleanup unanswered questions :-)

Comment: I edited the code according your suggestion, but when I execute this and submit form, it wasn't holding the value

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. To make better answer for you. How you get all your countries? I mean, you need a collection of countries. How you request these values?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gansai/qAMpM/ - Here is countries.js javascript file for your reference

Comment: @ronquiq see my jsfiddle, i hope you can use this one. (also added to my answer.  http://jsfiddle.net/eLProva/5mU76/

Comment: I was getting the selected value, but we need to import value in dropdown list as usual

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="country" onchange="print_state('state',this.selectedIndex);" id="country"/>
    <option <?php if($youroldval==$myform->value('country')){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $myform->value("country");  ?>"/><?php echo $myform->value("country");  ?></option>
</select>
```

You must store your old value of form

Comment: Thank You. Could I know how will we get "$youroldval", I amn't storing the data to database yet, its still at client place

Comment: then save it in session $_SESSION['youroldval'] = $_POST['fieldname']; then use $_SESSION['youroldval'] but remember to check if isset